# Why can't vue table components render data?

Tags: javascript, vue-component, element

I want to write a table component because there are tables in multiple pages in the project.But can't render data now.

Here is my code,

HTML:

```
    <resource-table :TableData="resourceCodeTableData" :CodeColumns="resourceCodeColumns"></resource-table>
```

JS:

```
   var tableCom = `
                <el-table :data="TableData" class="pj-table" height="400px" stripe border>
                    <el-table-column
                            v-for="column in CodeColumns" :prop="column.prop"
                            :label="column.label">
                        <template scope="scope">
                            <span v-html="scope.row[column.prop]"></span>
                        </template>
                    </el-table-column>
                </el-table>
                `;

Vue.component('resource-table', {
    props: ['TableData', 'CodeColumns'],
    template: 'tableCom'
});

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});
```

resourceCodeTableData:

```
[{"deviceType": "tttt"}]
```

resourceCodeColumns:

```
[{"label":"deviceType","prop": "deviceType"}]
```

Please point out the error of my code, thank you very much.

Comment: Use kebab case for props in template. Change it to `<resource-table :table-data="resourceCodeTableData" :code-columns="resourceCodeColumns"></resource-table> `

Comment: Are you sure you have registered component `el-table` and `el-table-column`?

Comment: And also, you need `key` property when using `v-for`.

Comment: Thanks,but it doesn't work